# Java springboot POST request giving 404

Tags: spring-boot, post, postman

I am trying a `POST` request in `POSTMAN` but even though its reaching the tomcat server node, I get following error in my `localhost_access.log` file

```
"POST /app/MyService/myControllerMethod HTTP/1.1" 404 1010
```

My Controller class is something like this :

```
@Controller("myServicecontroller")
@RequestMapping({"/MyService"})
public class MyServiceController {

    @RequestMapping(value = {"myControllerMethod"}, method = {RequestMethod.POST})
    public String myControllerMethodBackgroundCallBack(HttpServletRequest httpReq,
            @RequestBody String request) {
             // rest piece of code
          }

     }
```

Now my postman curl I am trying with empty data (tried with some value also) but get above 404 error response

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://my-ip-address:8080/app/MyService/myControllerMethod' \
--header 'Accept: application/json' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--header 'My-Header-One: lskdnansdlknalkasndl' \
--header 'My-Header-Two: sadasdsa' \
--data-raw '{}'
```

What am I doing wrong? (`app` in above url is my service which works fine in other requests)

Same thing when I try with following code it is able to hit the api 200

```
HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
PostMethod postMethod = new PostMethod(url);
postMethod.setRequestBody(requestString);
httpClient.setConnectionTimeout(httpReadTimeOut);

httpClient.executeMethod(postMethod);
```

Comment: There is a whitespace at the end of your definition of the request mapping for the method. Copy & paste error...?
`value = {"myControllerMethod "}`

Comment: @StefanBillmaier sorry that's a typo over here in stack overflow while changing the names of my method. corrected it.

Comment: Try to add some logging to see if anything goes wrong when Spring MVC is working on the request:
`logging.level.web=DEBUG
# log request details; needs logging.level.web set to DEBUG or TRACE
spring.mvc.log-request-details=true
spring.mvc.log-resolved-exception=true`
You may add these to your application.properties.

Comment: @StefanBillmaier in catalina getting `29 Oct 2022 16:47:10,406 ERROR http-nio-8080-exec-277 org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter - Cannot forward to error page for request [/app/MyService/myControllerMethod] as the response has already been committed. As a result, the response may have the wrong status code. If your application is running on WebSphere Application Server you may be able to resolve this problem by setting com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.invokeFlushAfterService to false`

Comment: @arqam - I found the root cause. Please read my answer to know the fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have successfully replicated this issue and found the root cause.

**Root Cause**

`@ResponseBody` annotation is missing in **myControllerMethodBackgroundCallBack** method.

**Fix**

```
    @RequestMapping(value = {"myControllerMethod"}, method = {RequestMethod.POST})
    @ResponseBody
    public String myControllerMethodBackgroundCallBack(HttpServletRequest httpReq,
            @RequestBody String request) {
             // rest piece of code
          }

     }
```

**Why?**

`@ResponseBody` annotation is required with `@Controller` annotation and if use `@RestController` annotation then `@ResponseBody` annotation is not required.

In Short-

`@RestController` = `@Controller` + `@ResponseBody`

You can read more about `@Controller` and `@RestController` here https://medium.com/@akshaypawar911/java-spring-framework-controller-vs-restcontroller-3ef2eb360917